# OneNote converts Outlook Appointments to Series Appointment

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, onenote

When I attach OneNote notes to an existing nonrecurring Outlook Appointment the OneNote note contains a link to this Item. If I open this link from OneNote the Appointment will be converted to a appointment series with no enddate (default series settings). 
Does anyone know an Hotfix addressing this issue or a way to programatically prevent from Outlook doing this.

This happens in multiple Tested versions Outlook/OneNote 2010-2016

Background information: I am working on an C# Outlook Addin where in special cases Series without an end date are not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug in Outlook since at least 2010. MS confirmed that they can reproduce it and we will see if and when they do something about it